# Java: Conversion of String to byte array, then to long value and vice versa

Tags: java, arrays

Basically, I'm looking for .NET's ***BitConverter***.

I need to get bytes from String, then parse them to long value and store it. After that, read long value, parse to byte array and create original String. How can I achieve this in Java?

Edit: Someone did already ask similar question. I am looking more like for samples then javadoc reference ...

Comment: What's wrong with javadoc reference?

Comment: Why would you convert byte[] to long[] to store them.  The problem is that long must be multiple of 8 bytes long, so if your string is not a multiple of 8, you will have to record the length as well.  Why not save the byte[] as a byte[], this is the simplest and more efficient.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman It's something that I did myself and wasn't able to figure out how to solve described problem though :)

Comment: @The javadoc, like most API documentation, is much better at answering "what does this do?" than it is at answering "how do I do this?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` has a `getBytes` method. You could use this to get a byte array.

To store the byte-array as longs, I suggest you wrap the byte-array in a `ByteBuffer` and use the `asLongBuffer` method.

To get the `String` back from an array of bytes, you could use the `String(byte[] bytes)` constructor.

```
String input = "hello long world";

byte[] bytes = input.getBytes();
LongBuffer tmpBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).asLongBuffer();
    
long[] lArr = new long[tmpBuf.remaining()];
for (int i = 0; i < lArr.length; i++)
    lArr[i] = tmpBuf.get();
    
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lArr));
// store longs...
    
// ...load longs
long[] longs = { 7522537965568945263L, 7955362964116237412L };
byte[] inputBytes = new byte[longs.length * 8];
ByteBuffer bbuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(inputBytes);
for (long l : longs)
    bbuf.putLong(l);
System.out.println(new String(inputBytes));
```

Note that you probably want to store an extra integer telling how many bytes the long-array actually stores, since the number of bytes may not be a multiple of 8.

Comment: And how do you get original string back from bytes?

Comment: How would you parse the long back to byte array?

Comment: what are those long numbers? if I change string to "Hello joe world" result is again "hello long world"

Comment: I manually entered the numbers corresponding to `"hello long world"` to simulate a "load longs from disk" :-)   You could replace `longs = { ...` with `longs = lArr;` instead to short-cut it :)

Comment: OK, so let's get original string. I updated code to: long[] longs = lArr; With "hello long world" it works, with "hello joe world" it doesn't. Try it yourself :)

Comment: @Xorty, @Peter, that's why I wrote my last comment. Keeping track of the actual number of characters isn't that hard. Pad it with spaces, and save an int telling how many characters the string consisted of.

Comment: @Xorty, The code doesn't handle strings which are not a multiple of 8 bytes long.  See his note at the end. long's are a multiple of 8 bytes, which doesn't make them a good choice for storing text.

Comment: btw I originally needed one long value not array of longs ... :)

Comment: or 8 bytes, or 9x 7-bit values. ;)

Comment: So i learned ... I need to try different way, thanx for making things clear however