# Converting string to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, rsa

I'm using **RSA** encryption for converting simpletext to encrypted form.

`my plain text is : hello`

`encrypted text : [B@d7eed7`

Now, how to convert encrypted text into simple plain text
i'm using following code

```
KeyPairGenerator keygenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
keygenerator.initialize(1024, random);

KeyPair keypair = keygenerator.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey privateKey = keypair.getPrivate();
PublicKey publicKey = keypair.getPublic();
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

String arrayStr = "[b@d7eed7";
byte ciphertext = arrayStr.getBytes();
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] cleartext1 = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
System.out.println("the decrypted cleartext is: " + new String(cleartext1));
```

i'm getting **javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero**

need help !!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483181/javax-crypto-badpaddingexception-data-must-start-with-zero-exception

Comment: I'm pretty sure your encrypted text is _not_ `[B@d7eed7` (or at least not in the way you think).

Comment: it is not for encryption, encryption part have been already done. Now, i've the encrypted text `[b@77eed7`, which is in string format, now i want to return it back to the original text.

Comment: There is a lot of wrongness potential in this question, even before the wrong assumption that `byte [].toString()` is meaningful. You should not even be trying to take the byte [] result of encryption and converting it to character string unless you need to transfer it through a character-only channel. In that case, you should using something like base64 encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `[B@d7eed7` is not the encrypted text. It simply shows the type and the address of the byte array, not its contents.

For more information, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5500020/367273

Comment: i've already visited that link, but it hard for me to understand. I' mean i didn't get what he/she is saying for the solution

Comment: @coders_zone: He is saying "Use `new String(array, encoding)` and not `array.toString()`".

Comment: then, how can i decrypt the same array to the plain text.

Comment: i was trying `new String(encryptarr,"Base64")`, then it showing exception `UnsupportedEncodeingException: Base64`

Comment: Base64 is not a character encoding. Do it like this: encode your array into base64 and use ASCII character encoding for the output string.

Comment: can you please give any example..??

Answer (score 2):

I just looked to the "Related" part on the right side of the screen and... [Convert Java string to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499924/convert-java-string-to-byte-array)

Answer (score 1):

to convert string to byte array you can use the following:

```
String source = "0123456789";
byte[] byteArray = source.getBytes("specify encoding alongside endianess");// e.g "UTF-16LE", "UTF-16"..
```

For more info you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228987/convert-string-to-byte), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536054/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-string-and-vice-versa) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432147/java-conversion-of-string-to-byte-array-then-to-long-value-and-vice-versa).

Good luck!